# Delete entries by matching two tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 tables and i need to delete the content of table A by two checks.
I should work like:
Delete from character_skills where class_index is not 0 or class_index is not dual_class 1 in character_subclasses.
I have try:

```
DELETE FROM character_skills
WHERE class_index != 0
  AND class_index IN (SELECT class_index FROM character_subclasses WHERE dual_class = 0);
```

But with this he ignore the dual_class check and delete all entries from character_skills where is not 0.

Anybody have a idea?

---

i trying both versions but he still delete all where is not 0 inside character_skills.

thats my table structures:
[character_skills](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3SAnL.png)
[character_subclasses](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Dija.png)

Comment: Run the select stand-alone and see what it returns...

Comment: if i run it with select he show me all entrys where class_index is not 0

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you have multiple tables, you should qualify *all* column references.  This query:

```
DELETE cs FROM character_skills cs
    WHERE cs.class_index <> 0 AND
          cs.class_index IN (SELECT csc.class_index
                             FROM character_subclasses csc
                             WHERE csc.dual_class = 0
                            );
```

Should do what you describe.  However, if `character_subclasses` does not have a column called `class_index`, then this will fail.  And the query in your version would delete all rows.

Comment: trying. still delete all entries where is not 0 in character_skills.

Answer (score 0):

check this (in MSSQL it works):

```
DELETE FROM character_skills cs
INNER JOIN character_subclasses csu ON cs.class_index =csu.class_index 
WHERE cs.class_index <> 0 and dual_class = 0
```

Comment: DELETE FROM character_skills cs
INNER JOIN character_subclasses csu ON cs.class_index =csu.class_index 
WHERE cs.class_index <> 0 and dual_class = 0
> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'cs
INNER JOIN character_subclasses csu ON cs.class_index =csu.class_index 
WHE' at line 1
> Time: 0s

Comment: sorry i thought its sql server . i will edit this comment .
in MSSQL it will work .